# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un <div> de ancho automatico?

Tags: html, css

Tengo un chat web y las burbujas de conversación tienen un ancho fijo. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el ancho se variable en función del contenido que se va colocando?

Dejo el fragmento del `css`.

```
.chat-bubble {
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(126,156,163,0.55);
    padding: 5px 7px;
    width: 300px;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Puedes pasar el fragmento de HTML que genera la burbuja?

Comment: No debería bastar con quitarle el ancho establecido?

Comment: Julio, cambia la propiedad `width` `min-width` y `max-width` de manera que controles un ancho mínimo y un máximo para el contenido.

Comment: Tal y como dice @Aprendiz, el problema está en que por mucho que le pongas el `max-width`, tienes una anchura fija por lo que ignorará la propiedad `max-width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pudieras hacerlo a través de la propiedad `max-width` que ayuda a establecer el ancho máximo que el elemento va a tener.

De este modo:

```
div{
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 20%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Haces uso de:

- `word-wrap: break-word;` por que cuando el contenedor sea de un ancho mínimo determinado tendrá desbordamiento del texto interno, entonces hacemos que los textos se vayan al siguiente renglón previniendo se salgan
- Le indicamos que tome el **`20%`** de ancho máximo, lo cual hará que por ejemplo:

Se comportaría de este modo:

- `window` es de **`500px`** entonces el `div` mide **`121px`**
- `window` es de **`812px`** entonces el `div` mide **`183px`**

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        div{
          background-color: red;
          max-width: 20%;
          word-wrap: break-word;
          padding: 12px;
          font-size: 10px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
      Hola a todos 
      <p>
        Envío un cordial saludo a todos y todas quienes forman estan comunidad.
      </p>
    </div>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
          alert(window.innerWidth)
          alert(document.querySelector("div").offsetWidth)
        })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

la mejor opción es jugar con el display de los elementos y elk ancho que que le otorgas a cada uno de ellos, dejo un ejemplo a continuación:

html:

```
<div>
    <p class="chat-bubble">hola</p>
   </div>
   <div>
   <p class="chat-bubble">hola, esto es una prueba de como mejor funciona el ancho 
   variable</p>
  </div>
```

css:

```
div {width:100%; display:block}

 .chat-bubble {
   border-radius: 7px;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(126,156,163,0.55);
   padding: 5px 7px;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 50px;
   max-width: 100%;
   white-space: normal;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Si quieres que el ancho se amolde al contenido, con quitar el ancho bastaría:

Ejemplo 1:

```
 <div style="width:20%;">
    <div>Aquí el contenido del div se ajusta al padre, un 20%</div>
 </div>
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
 <div>
    <div>Aquí el contenido del div se va ampliando dependiendo de su 
     contenido, sin ancho fijo.
    </div>
 </div>
```